# Use a variable as a coordinate in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:40]
    \addplot {x};
    \def\a{\pgfmathparse{1+1}\pgfmathresult}
    %\draw (\a,20)--(axis cs:20,0);
    \node at (axis cs:30,30) {\a};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The node gives me the correct output, while the draw command won't work as expected. Why?
(Uncommenting `\draw` breaks the code.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\pgfmathparse` macro is not expandable and can't be used inside coordinates. Placing `\pgfmathresult` behind it, inside another macro like `\a` or on its own doesn't change anything on that. You need to place the result, like `\pgfmathresult`, which is expandable in the coordinates. However `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten by *any* internal math operation and therefor should not be used!
Either use `\let\a=\pgfmathresult` (the `=` is optional) or `\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1+1}` (recommended) as already posted by you and Jake, respectively, or `\edef\a{\pgfmathresult}` to store the current value of `\pgfmathresult` into `\a` which then can be used safely inside an coordinate.

The reason why your original `\a` works inside the node content (`{\a}`) is that this part is typeset as a box. The content of a box do not need to be fully expandable, but is executed, i.e. the `\pgfmathparse` is executed as normal and then `\pgfmathresult` is typeset right away before it can be changed by any other code.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really say why, but the following works fine:

```
\pgfmathparse{1+1}\let\a=\pgfmathresult
```